# RealTimeDatabase.once() runs repeatedly

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get data from a `RealTimeDatabase` using `.once()` but it results in returning the same data multiple times. Here is my code:

```
userData(userdata) async {
    print("here");

    await databaseReference.child('users').once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      bool userexists = false;
      var dataMap = snapshot.value as Map;
      dataMap.forEach((key, value) {
        if (key == userdata.uid) {
          userexists = true;
          print("add to player model");
          print(value['avatar']);
        }
      });
    });
}
```

Running above function has following output:

```
flutter: here
flutter: add to player model
flutter: default
flutter: add to player model
flutter: default
flutter: add to player model
flutter: default
```

As you can see 'here' was output only once, this means the function wasn't called multiple times. Following is a screenshot of the database

[image]

The id should match only once and the output should be only once instead of multiple times. Can someone please guide me how to fix this. Thank you

Comment: instead value['avatar'] try value.avatar

Comment: @Giorgi Thank you for your kind response. Please note value['avatar'] output is already there. The issue is that output is being displayed three times.